# ¿Como configurar prettier pluggin vscode, para que respete los espacios que le doy a una linea de codigo?

Tags: vscode

como indico, uso prettier para dar formato a mi codigo, pero odio tener esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y que prettier me lo convierta en esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

existe alguna forma de indicarle a prettier que respete los espacios o tabulaciones?

Comment: mira este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140595/show-whitespace-characters-in-visual-studio-code/40037865#40037865

Comment: wannabe yo no me referia a los white spaces, sino a la accion del formateador, de darle todo un solo espacio, mientras que yo prefiero tenerlo todo alineado, sé que intelijell respeta eso, pero en vscode no he conseguido como hacerlo